# Regex to get the string before and after the matches

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting

I have written a regex to match URLs containing pattern `..;` and similar, for example,
`abc.com/..;/abc` or `abc.com/..;/..;/abc` or `abc.com/..;;/abc` and so on.

This is how my regex looks like `"/*[.]{2,};+/"`, it is able to match in all the cases that I have tried and then I can throw an exception but what if instead of throwing an exception, I want to convert these URLs to remove the matched string and get something like `abc.com/abc`.

Comment: You know of the `String.replaceAll` and `String,replaceFirst` methods ?   Eg `String result = urlStr.replaceAll("/*[.]{2,};+/", “/”);`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: How about fixing the code that produces those URLs?

Comment: @Holger the code is not producing those urls, its coming from the client.

Comment: @racraman replaceAll can be expensive which is why I was avoiding that.

Comment: So the client does not consist of code? Or are you telling me the user is inserting dots and semicolons into the URL for no good reason?

Comment: @Holger its a vulnerability where an attacker can insert dot-dot-semicolon to traverse the parent directory. dot-dot is normalized by tomcat but dot-dot-semicolon does not.

Comment: So you’re assuming an intentional attack? Then, return an error page for this invalid URL, instead of trying to convert it to a valid one. Besides that, the correct way to handle relative paths is 1) construct a `Path` object from the query, 2) normalize the `Path` object, 3) check that the resulting path is still a sub path of the permitted ancestor path.

Answer (score 1):

So from your comment, if your concern is the performance of replaceAll, you can reduce that by arranging to compile the RegEx Pattern just once (at class loading time), so :

```
private static final PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/*[.]{2,};+/”);

String result = PATTERN.matcher(str).replaceAll(“/“);
```

The compiled pattern is thread-safe, so is safe to be used in a constant like this.

There is, of course, a `replaceFirst(String repl)` as well.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-